# home made ethernet cable speed degradation. what is reasonable?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

i made my own cat5e cable  for wired ethernet backhaul between my main router and an Access Point (2nd router). the cable is about 80 feet long. one end i put male rj45 and the other i wired to a female 'block' that connects to a wall plate

i tried to follow online instructions and be careful about the twists!

internet speed test shows 150Mpbs coming direcrtly out of router but only 75Mpbs after connecting the homemade cable inline.

is it common to have so much loss of signal quality?

is it 'practical' to make homemade cables that run at these high speeds?

should i only wire male connectors on homemade cables and use those little store bought 'extenders' (female to female)? i ask because the male connectors seem easier to wire than the female

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you wired the pairs correctly? (i.e. paired 3+6 and 4+5, not 3+4 and 5+6) Did you wire all four pairs? Are you testing the cable directly between computer and first router, or is the second router involved in the tests as well?

Comment: "is it common to have so much loss of signal quality?" - No; But how much signal quality loss you will see entirely depends on the shielding of the cable, what the cable runs up against, and a bunch of information you didn't include.

Comment: This is almost always caused by not wiring the pairs properly as grawity said. Every pin must go straight through to the same pin on the other side and the correct pins must be mapped to pairs. Check out [this link](https://incentre.net/ethernet-cable-color-coding-diagram/) and make sure you followed either the T-568A or the T-568B (recommended) diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve the same specifications listed for the Category of the cable. Cat5, Cat5e, and Cat6 will do 1Gbps up to 100m. Cat6 will do 10Gbps up to 55m, and Cat6a will do 10Gbps up to 100m. There should never be any performance degradation due to the cable.

If you trust the quality of the cable and are not meeting these specifications, your termination is probably bad. Cut the connector off, verify you are ordering the wires per either the T-568A or the T-568B standard, and re-terminate the cable. In lieu of a fancy cable tester, your only test will be using it and seeing how it performs.

Comment: A simple test would be running a traffic generator across it, or even simpler, just pinging with large packets and little delay. You can also check the interface stats for errors, for cable problems there're plenty of them usually.